# Rest GET request. How to add more parameters

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a REST GET endpoint which returns the simple data. But based on parameters I need to return more data. There are two implementations that I can think of. But need suggestions on which is better or if there is any other better solution.

**Option 1:**

1. GET /carts/1234 -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products and savings.
2. GET /carts/1234?ship=true -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings and shipping calculation.
3. GET /carts/1234?ship=true&promo=true -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings, shipping calculation and promotion calculation.
4. GET /carts/1234?ship=true&promo=true&product=true -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings, shipping calculation, promotion calculation and cart items.

**Option 2:**

Is to use bit operator to specifiy what time of read set to return.

1. GET /carts/1234 -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products and savings.
2. GET /carts/1234?readset=100 -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings and shipping calculation.
3. GET /carts/1234?readset=110 -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings, shipping calculation and promotion calculation.
4. GET /carts/1234?readset=111 -> returns simple cart data with total items, total products, savings, shipping calculation, promotion calculation and cart items.

Need suggestions on which is better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first is more readable. What are you trying to solve with the second?

Comment: As Evert mentioned, the first is more readable, aditionaly is more flexible and expandable, and should be easiest to handle, resulting in better readable handling code.

Comment: Option 2 is to reduce the length of URL